# how to implement a custom video player with media controls in android?

Tags: android, video-streaming, custom-controls, android-custom-view, android-videoview

it should just take video server url. should buffer and start playing video.

are there any libraries available for playing a video with buffering ?
How to implement custom video player with media controls similar to youtube?

Comment: Did you find a path to a solution?

Comment: @TonyCruze I didn't find